# how to parse json in RecyclerView with android?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I get json from api :

```
{
    "SuccessInfo": [       
        {
            "key": "clothes,color",
            "value": [
                "pink",
                "green",
                "yellow",
                "white",
                "blue",
                "black"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "clothes,type",
            "value": [
                "female",
                "male",
                "child"
            ]
        }
```

accounting json , I design a class :

```
public class Clothes{
   
    public static class SuccessInfoBean{
           
        private String key;
        private List<String> value;
           
        public SuccessInfoBean(String key , List<String> value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

in MainActivity, I want to know how to parse "value" ?

```
    List<Clothes.SuccessInfoBean> infoBean = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(myJson2.toString());
    JSONArray  jsonArray = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("SuccessInfoBean");
     
    for (int j =0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++){
       JSONObject object2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
       String key2 = object2.getString("key");
       stringList.add(object2.getString("value"));
```

I user infoBean.add(key,stringList) will get error,

which part is wrong?

Comment: You should take a look at [Retrofit library](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  String key2 = object2.getString("key");
  JSONArray jsonValue = object2.getJSONArray("value");
  for (int i=0; i < jsonValue.length();i ++){
    stringList.add(jsonValue.getString(i)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a recyeler view inside adapter class instead have look at this **expandable-recycler-view** https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view.

Make your another view inside this.
So your checkbox will be child view/ layout and Clothes and color will be parent layout.